# Extract some digits after word id

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a Name column and a Log column.

```
Name            Log
Michelle        Bad 222 news travels id 54585 fast.
Lucy            Barking 333 dogs id 545584 seldom bite.
Green           Beauty is 444 in the id 85955 eyes of the beholder.
Gail            Beggars 123 can't be ID 4658 choosers.
```

I want to extract only the ID digits from log column. Note that the word ID could be capitalized or not. Hence, the output should be like this:

```
Name        ID
Michelle    54585
Lucy        545584
Green       85955
Gail        4658
```

I tried to use the following query:

```
select name
     , substring(log from E'^(.*?)[id< ]') as id
from mytable;
```

However, I cannot have the output I need.

Comment: The important thing is to return the digits after the word id. So, let's say I trim 10 characters after the word ID and I return only the digits. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines should work. Since you didn't provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements, I just used one row in a common table expression.

```
with data as (
  select 'Michelle' as name, 'Bad 333 id 54342 wibble' as log
)
select name, substring(substring(log::text, '((id|ID) [0-9]+)'), '[0-9]+') 
from data 
where log::text ~* 'id [0-9]+';
```

The nested `substring()` calls first return the id number along with the string 'id', then return just the id number.